# How to close an app after showing a dialog?

Tags: android, dialog, internet-connection

I have almost completed my app development and I have even allowed a way to show up a toast message if there is no internet connection. I need to know how to close an app after showing a dialog if there is no internet connection?

- My app is a webview app. So when user turn on the app, the app must check for internet connection. and display a dialog box if no network and the app must close after showing dialog.

OR

- I don't want users to see the "webpage not available" page, so if there is no internet connection, the app must close after showing a dialog box with one button 'close'. Or is there any way to redirect users to a text in directory which shows no internet connection?

I need those code only; all the other codes have been done and are working properly.

Answer (score 2):

Just invoke finish() to destroy activity in the onClick() function of dialog. Like:

```
...
builder.setMessage('There is no connection!! Please close the activity!')
               .setPositiveButton('close', new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                       finish();
                   }
               })
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can popup a dialog after checking the internet connectivity as follows

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Connection Error")
    .setMessage("You are not connected to Internet.")
    .setPositiveButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
           // finish the activity here or,
           // redirect to another activity
        }
     })
    .show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check your internet connectivity before setting the view to the activity.

Like :

```
if(connnected){
    setContentView(layoutId);
}else{
    show a tosat with information no internet;
    finish activity.
}
```

Comment: To format code/pseudocode, indent by four spaces (or use the code button in the editor).

Answer (score 1):

call `finish()` method on your activity once user clicks on dialogue

Comment: give more context and code and explain why this might be a solution